# JINJA loop doesn't display correct variable Python

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I have beautiful soup to search internet for information. I want to send the result to html with render template and in html loop with JINJA. Beautiful soup gives me the result in bs.tag format type. I couldn't remove unwanted tags and save only searched data in this format, so I decided to convert it to string and then replace unwanted characters:

.py

```
   title = soup.find_all(class_="BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd")
   for v in title:
       r1 = str(v)
       r2 = r1.replace('<div class="BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd">', "")
   return render_template('test.html', r2=r2)
```

.html

```
{% for item in title %}
   <div>{{ r2 }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The strange thing is although I am providing **r2** in render_template and in html, I am getting data with the `<div..` Which shouldn't be in **r2** as I have replaced it with "". It seems that system somehow takes **r1** or **v** variable instead of **r2**. I can not test which data is taken as tested in console with print() I am getting correct values for all variables...

Comment: You are assigning to `r2` repeatedly in a loop; the value that you are passing to your template is the one from the final iteration of the loop, all of the previous values are lost.  As for why the replacement isn't working, are you sure that the HTML includes the exact text `<div class="BNeawe vvjwJb AP7Wnd">`, with not a single character different?  In particular, the actual tag might use single instead of double quotes, or might have some attributes other than `class`.

Comment: Jason, I am replacing identical class value which I was used as a key for soup.find_all, therefore I assume it must be the same. In my understanding if it was printed in console in a correct way, the same result should be in html template...I was messing around with the quotes as you suggested, but without any results...

Answer (score 0):

According to Template Designer Documentation: (https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#html-escaping)

> When generating HTML from templates, there’s always a risk that a variable will include characters that affect the resulting HTML. There are two approaches:
> a) manually escaping each variable; or
> b) automatically escaping everything by default."

and

> When automatic escaping is enabled, everything is escaped by default except for values explicitly marked as safe. Variables and expressions can be marked as safe either in:
> The context dictionary by the application with markupsafe.Markup
> The template, with the |safe filter."